# prevent image encoding in java

Tags: java, android

I have code to upload image and text to the server, but my code encodes the image and in the server the image should be decoded.

I want to prevent image encoding. I've tried some ways but they're not working.

I don't know how to do this. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
public class Share_food extends Activity {

ProgressDialog prgDialog;
String encodedString;
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
String imgPath, fileName;
Bitmap bitmap;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
EditText ti,desc;
TextView tv;
String url="http://example.com/index.php";

@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.share_food);
    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
    ti= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
    desc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.share_desc22);

    //getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
    //getActionBar().setIcon( new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
    //getActionBar().setTitle("");
}


public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgPath));
            String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
            fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
            params.put("filename", fileName);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            imgPath="2";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "error...!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}

public void uploadImage(View v) {

    if (imgPath != null && !imgPath.isEmpty()) {
        prgDialog.setMessage("process");
        prgDialog.show();
        encodeImagetoString();
    } else {
        prgDialog.setMessage("process");
        prgDialog.show();
        triggerImageUpload();
    }
}

public void encodeImagetoString() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        };

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath,
                    options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

            prgDialog.setMessage("upload");

            params.put("title", ti.getText().toString().trim());

            //desc
            //params.put("desc",desc.getText().toString().trim());

            params.put("image", encodedString);

            triggerImageUpload();
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}

public void triggerImageUpload() {

    params.put("title", ti.getText().toString().trim());

    //desc
    //params.put("desc", desc.getText().toString().trim());

    makeHTTPCall();
}

public void makeHTTPCall() {
    prgDialog.setMessage("connecting");
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post(url,
            params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                                      String content) {
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    if (statusCode == 404) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else if (statusCode == 500) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "error !!!"
                                        + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (prgDialog != null) {
        prgDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you have to decode the string in receiving end and save the decoded one. post the code of receiving end too for more convenience.